# Exponential Distribution and Possible Memoryless Property

Tags: exponential-function, conditional-probability

[image]

My attempt :

[image]

Do you guys think this is right? This might have something do the with the exponential's memoryless property?

Comment: I think you might need more here. Note that in your proof, you are assuming that for any $u,v$ the events  $X_1 > Y+u$ and $X_2 > Y+v$ are independent. However, notice that both events depend on the variable $Y$ and so it doesn't seem immediate to me that they would be independent.

Comment: Thanks Tom ! I think I know what to do now !

Comment: @RyanJones For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).